# How to iterate over two collections (lists) and remove duplicate values?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists `potentialDupes` and `mainList`. I'm trying to remove all potentialDupes from main list if any values are the same.

```
potentialDupes = [(123, "John Doe"), (456, 'John Doe'), (789, 'Marie Doe'), (098, 'Marie Doe'), (765, 'Michael Doe')]

mainList = [(123, "John Doe"), (456, 'John Doe'), (789, 'Marie Doe'), (098, 'Marie Doe'), (765, 'Michael Doe'), (432, 'Amanda Doe')]
```

I'm trying to get the following as output of the above:

```
output = [(432, 'Amanda Doe')]
```

I've tried the following:

```
list(set(potentialDupes))
output = list(set(potentialDupes) - set(mainList))
```

However, when I printed output it returned empty list:

```
[]
```

Could someone help me with this please? thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried with `output = list(set(mainList) - set(potentialDupes))` ?

Comment: Also note that `098` is not a valid Python token (it looks like an octal number, but neither 8 nor 9 is a valid octal digit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# You need to change 098 to 98 
potentialDupes = [(123, "John Doe"), (456, 'John Doe'), (789, 'Marie Doe'), (98, 'Marie Doe'), (765, 'Michael Doe')]

mainList = [(123, "John Doe"), (456, 'John Doe'), (789, 'Marie Doe'), (98, 'Marie Doe'), (765, 'Michael Doe'), (432, 'Amanda Doe')]

output  = list(set(mainList) - set(potentialDupes))
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is essentially doing what the difference method does:

```
set(mainList).difference(set(potentialDupes))
```

However, as Scott said, the order matters:

```
output = list(set(mainList - set(potentialDupes))
```

Comment: This answer obscures what the original problem was (that is, the order of the operands).

Comment: Exactly. It is all to do with the order of the operands, and not to do with whether `a - b` or `a.difference(b)` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can help you with as it removes the duplicate values automatically and then converts it back to list the following function can help you with that

```
def rem_dup(x):
    return list(dict.fromkeys(x))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
 list(set(mainList).difference(set(potentialDupes)))
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. Why should the OP try this?